# Sending email from any provider to a fixed address

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemailer

I have a contact form where the sender could be from gmail, outlook or any other provider and the receiver is always the same.

1. How can I send email in this case?
2. I need to switch params based on the sender's provider or I can send without them?
3. Nodemailer auto-detect provider from the address or I need to specify it in the smtp transport?

**UPDATE: Is there a different solution than nodemailer?**

I'm expecting to receive email from any kind of address fulfilling the contact form.

Comment: You are sending an email *to* any provider, not *from* them. Or you are sending an email to yourself with the contact information as the body. The email provider of the user does not matter remotely.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand, nodemailer is not to send from any provider but only to send from a specific provider to any others.